# How get data from database with multiply tables?

Tags: php, mysql

**Hello Guys!**

I have a problem with get result from database correctly. I have lot of table but this is not important right now. I have a table look like that:

```
***PUBLISHER_DEVELOPER table***
pd_id : [int] AUTO PRIMARY
pd_name: [varchar]
pd_type: [integer] (0,1 or 2)

***GAME_INFO table***
g_id: [int] AUTO PRIMARY
g_label: [varchar]
g_publisher: [integer]
g_developer: [integer]
```

The connections beetwen the tables are this:

PUBLISHER_DEVELOPER : GAME_INFO = 1:LOT

I would like to get the game info with the publisher and developers normal name, but i always got ZERO row returned.

**My SQL query:**

```
*SELECT pd_name, pd_name, g_label FROM PUBLISHER_DEVELOPER,GAME_INFO WHERE pd_id = g_publisher AND pd_id = g_developer*
```

Any idea what i do wrong?

Comment: there is no relation between these tables (foreign key) how can u expect data to be return?

Comment: look into doing a `join` - http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumedly you want two joins to the `PUBLISHER_DEVELOPER` table to get back both the publisher and the developer.

```
SELECT p.pd_name AS p_name, d.pd_name AS d_name, g_label
FROM GAME_INFO
JOIN PUBLISHER_DEVELOPER p ON p.pd_id = g_publisher
JOIN PUBLISHER_DEVELOPER d ON d.pd_id = g_developer
```

[SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6b504/4/0)

For the query in your comment, a similar rewrite would look something like this.

```
SELECT f.fk_nev, k.fk_nev, k_nev, j_cim, j_megjelent, j_megjelenes, 
  j_cover, a_becenev, b_head, b_ci?m, b_cimke, b_lead, b_tartalom, 
  b_komment, b_datum, b_burl
FROM jatek_info ji
JOIN fejleszt_kiad f ON f.fk_id = ji.j_fejleszt  
JOIN fejleszt_kiad k ON k.fk_id = ji.j_kiad
JOIN jatek j ON j.j_jatek_info = ji.j_id  
JOIN blog b ON b.b_jatek = j.j_id
JOIN admin a ON a.a_id = b.b_szerzo
```

I'm guessing to a certain extent how your tables are linked, but I think that should be correct.

Note that there is a `?` in one of the field names which I'm assuming is a non-ASCII character that got corrupted when you cut and paste the query into the comment. Be sure to fix that if you're cutting and pasting my code back.

Comment: Thank you very mutch! That was what i want! Can modify this code just like above?

SELECT fk_nev,fk_nev,k_nev,j_cim,j_megjelent,j_megjelenes,j_cover,a_becenev,b_head,b_cim,b_cimke,b_lead,b_tartalom,b_komment,b_datum,b_burl
      FROM fejleszt_kiad,kategoria,jatek_info,jatek,admin,blog
      WHERE fejleszt_kiad.fk_id = jatek_info.j_fejleszt
        AND fejleszt_kiad.fk_id = jatek_info.j_kiad
        AND jatek_info.j_id = jatek.j_jatek_info
        AND admin.a_id = blog.b_szerzo
        AND jatek.j_id = blog.b_jatek

Comment: I've updated my answer to show how you can modity that query.

Comment: Thank you very mutch! I change it and this is the corrrect! Thanks the lot of help me DUDE!

SELECT f.fk_nev, k.fk_nev, k_nev, j_cim, j_megjelent, j_megjelenes, 
  j_cover, a_becenev, b_head, b_cim, b_cimke, b_lead, b_tartalom, 
  b_komment, b_datum, b_burl
FROM kategoria, jatek_info ji
JOIN fejleszt_kiad f ON f.fk_id = ji.j_fejleszt  
JOIN fejleszt_kiad k ON k.fk_id = ji.j_kiad
JOIN jatek j ON j.j_jatek_info = ji.j_id  
JOIN blog b ON b.b_jatek = j.j_id
JOIN admin a ON a.a_id = b.b_szerzo

Answer (score 1):

Probably the publisher and developer are different. There should be a relationship between the first table and either the g_publisher or g_developer.

```
SELECT pd_name, pd_name, g_label FROM PUBLISHER_DEVELOPER INNER JOIN GAME_INFO ON pd_id = g_publisher

SELECT pd_name, pd_name, g_label FROM PUBLISHER_DEVELOPER INNER JOIN GAME_INFO ON pd_id = g_developer
```

Or

```
SELECT pd_name, pd_name, g_label FROM PUBLISHER_DEVELOPER LEFT OUTER JOIN GAME_INFO ON pd_id = g_publisher
```

Answer (score 0):

If g_publisher and g_developer both refer to PUBLISHER_DEVELOPER.pd_id then you can join to the table twice.

```
  SELECT pd_1.pd_name, pd_2.pd_name, gi.g_label FROM PUBLISHER_DEVELOPER pd_1, PUBLISHER_DEVELOPER pd_2, GAME_INFO gi WHERE pd_1.pd_id = gi.g_publisher AND pd_1.pd_id = gi.g_developer;
```

Comment: Sorry for my English. Here is a picture for my Tables.

http://kepfeltoltes.hu/130529/SQL_www.kepfeltoltes.hu_.jpg